intermittent water leak within bathroom walls
over the past week i have found puddles of water on my bathroom floor with no apparent source of the leaks.  I checked all of the exposed pipes from sinks to toilet to bath, no leaks.  Last night I heard water spraying within the walls which resulted in the largest pooling of water yet. So I opened the wall and found an area that was wet yet I could not find the source. No piping appeared to be leaking.
These leaks are not constant only appearing roughly every other day (this has happened 4 times in 10 days). And they have occurred in the evening, only for a short time.  i cleanup the puddles with wet vac and the floor remains dry until another occurrence, no continual leaking.  Plus the water system has remained pressurized, which i thought would result in a constant leakage. It has not.
Any ideas on what would cause significant yet sporadic water leaks?

Pressurize water supply pipes should leak all the time if there is a leak.  It might be possible to have a slow drip, but have high pressure spikes that causes a better leak, normal pressure is 40 but it goes to 100 for some reason.  You have not looked far enough for the leak.

What is above this leak location?  A 2nd floor where someone might be running something only in the evenings every other day and it's a drain leak, a roof with a possible vent leak only when it's raining?  Pictures would help.

i attempted to add pictures yet failed for some reason.

i attempted to add pictures yet failed for some reason.   My apt is on the top floor. Another apt is adjacent with the shower abutting the wall in my bath. At the start of this problem maintenance did enter that apt and recaulked the shower stall although no obvious gaps were seen.   The water from the leaks was not grey water rather it was totally clear, no particulates in the water, no odors.  There is no obvious sign of water leaks/staining on the wall boards nor on the shower stall structure abutting my apt.   Additionally the rate of the leak was not a slow drip/stream typically seen.

the picture shows the location of the leak. I've removed all wet insulation. the 2x4 through which the pipe goes was wet.  The back wall in the pic is actually the shower stall in the abutting apt.

also, there has been no rain recently and no sign of leaks coming from the roof. The insulation above the site of the leak remains dry.   My experience with plumbing leaks is that they stop when a valve is opened, releasing the line pressure. That is not occurring with this leak.  Thanks for your help and ideas.

Dry the pipes with a towel/paper towels.  Check back in about an hour to see if there is wetness again.

I still see no pics. However even without pics I can say that I had a tenant call me and tell me every sunday morning he gets up to find a puddle of water on the bathroom floor.  No other day of the week but sunday!  The mystery was solved when a crack in the tub was found in the unit above.  On sunday mornings the gentleman would shower with his girlfriend joining him.  The extra weight would open the crack. Point being , If your plumbing is showing nothing,  expect something from the apartment next door.
